# Copy a part of a QTableWidget in an other

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I've got a `QTableWidget` , and I use the method `selectedItems()` to get all the line selected in my QTableWidget. And now I want to copy all these line in an `other QTableWidget`, is there a particular function able to do this, or do I need to use a loop ?

If I need to use a loop, can you explain to me how it works ?

Thank You.

Comment: The items that you copy are not part of the widget, they are a part of the model. The `QTableWidget` uses an internal `QStandardItemModel` I think, and that model has copyable items. So it shouldn't be hard, since the model just exposes a tree of `QStandardItem`. So, any tree traversal from an intro to algorithms class will do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so if I understand, once I get all my tem with selectedItem, I have to put it int the other QTableWidget with function from QStandardItemModel ?

Comment: You don't put the items into a *widget*. You put them into a *model*. The widget is just a view onto the *model*. The `QTableWidget` is a convenience class that creates its own model for you. So, you can ask the second view for its model, and then you'll use the model's methods to add items to it. The view widget will automatically follow changes in the model.

Comment: Incidentally, you can have multiple views onto the same model. For example, you could create a third widget, a `QTableView`, to show the items from the second widget's model :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Kuba Ober, here is my solution :

```
//Model of my first QTableWidget
QItemSelectionModel *variableModel = ui->variableTableWidget->selectionModel();


//I take the cell selected in my QTableWidget ( I suppose only 1 cell is selected )
QModelIndex item;
QTableWidgetItem* itemCompleteTab = new QTableWidgetItem(); //You can't put a cell to another you have to use a new constructor
foreach (item, variableModel->selectedIndexes()) {
            itemCompleteTab->setText(ui->variableTableWidget->item(item.row(),item.column())->text());//Creation of my new cell
            ui->visualisationTableWidget->setItem(0,0,itemCompleteTab);//Add in the QTableWidget
        }
```